# Correct way of handling multiple housenumber options possible regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for help refactoring this messy code part.
It should handle the following house number formats

- 54 6 K 1 -> 546 K 1
- 54 6k 1 -> 546 K 1
- 20 H L -> 20 H L
- 1 10 -> 1 10
- 546 k1 -> 546 K 1
- 1K -> 1 K

```
    ?.toUpperCase()
    ?.match(/[^a-z]+|[a-z]|[a-z]/gi)
    ?.map((part) => `${part.trim()} `) // Split each part with a space
    .toString() // Revert to one string
    .replace(/,/g, "") // Remove all commas
    .replace(/\s+/g, " ") // Remove duplicate spaces
    .trim(); // Remove and spaces
```

Comment: I am not sure what the question is ?

Comment: Explain why `1 10` -> `1 10`  whille `54 6` K 1 -> `546` K 1 ?

Comment: Do you want to make a regex to handle all of those numbers above and handle wrong spaces too ?

Comment: It is not clear what the rule is; why does `54 6 K 1` become `546 K 1` but `1 10` remains the same? How do you discriminate whether to keep the space between two digits or not?

Comment: This function works correctly. 

But i think there must be a cleaner way. 
a house number exist of a basenumber 
a optional addition 
and an optional addition to the addition.

Maybe i didn't ask the question correctly.

Comment: Does the input consist of only numbers, letters, and spaces?

Comment: @VLAZ yes, that is correct!

Comment: I can definitely make it shorter but like the others, I am not sure if it's correct. [See this JSBin](https://jsbin.com/xacihukopu/1/edit?js,console). `54 6 K 1` gets converted to `54 6 K 1` and **not** `546 K 1`. If I change it to produce `546` without a space, that means that `1 10` will be turned to `110`. I can probably make both behave but I'm not sure if that doesn't break any other case. Can you make sure if the requirement and code here is correct?

Comment: I think we should go for the solution that won't break the common solutions.

I see now that 54 6 K 1 makes no sense. Lets just support 546 K 1

Comment: your logic is absurd, we can't turn it into an algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
function foo(input) {
  return !/[a-z]/i.test(input) ? input : input
    ?.toUpperCase()
    ?.match(/[^a-z\s]+|[a-z]/gi)
    .join("") // Revert to one string
    .replace(/(?<=\D)|(?=\D)/g, ' '); // Add spaces before/after a non-digit
}

console.log(foo("54 6 K 1"));
console.log(foo("54 6k 1"));
console.log(foo("20 H L"));
console.log(foo("1 10"));
console.log(foo("546 k1"));
console.log(foo("1K"));
```

First of all, test if your string contains a letter with `!/[a-z]/i.test(input)`. If not, return as is, there is no need processing it (`1 10` case). If there is a letter, perform the following:

- `?.toUpperCase()` - turn the string into upper case
- `?.match(/[^a-z\s]+|[a-z]/gi)` - tokenize the string into letter/non-letter & non-whitespace chunks
- `.join("")` - convert an array to string
- `.replace(/(?<=\D)|(?=\D)/g, ' ')` - add spaces between digit/non-digit chars.

See the [last regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s1fPT3/1).

Answer (score 0):

### Unnecessary regex pattern

```
  /[^a-z]+|[a-z]|[a-z]/gi
           ^^^^^ ^^^^^
```

This pattern is repeated. Since both parts match the same thing, there is no real need for the repetition and it one of them can be removed:

```
  /[^a-z]+|[a-z]/gi
```

### Overly broad regex pattern

```
  /[^a-z]+|[a-z]/gi
   ^^^^^^
```

The intention here is to catch "non-letters". However, the only characters in the inputs are letters, digits, and whitespace, so you should narrow it down. This will make dealing with the results much easier later on:

```
  /[0-9\s]+|[a-z]/gi
```

### Unneeded conversion

```
?.map((part) => `${part.trim()} `) // Split each part with a space
.toString() // Revert to one string
.replace(/,/g, "") // Remove all commas
.replace(/\s+/g, " ") // Remove duplicate spaces
.trim(); // Remove and spaces
```

These lines will work correctly but the problem is that there is too many of them. `toString()` will implicitly call `.join(",")` on the array and this is why `.replace(/,/g, "")` is needed. Then there are still two other lines to deal with whitespace.

Instead this can be simplified to just these two lines:

```
.map((part) => part.replace(/\s+/g, "")) // Remove unneeded spaces
.join(" ") // Revert to one string
```

First mapping to remove any spaces. This *works* because `part` will either contain numbers and spaces like `"54 6 "` or a single letter. We want the numbers combined into one, so removing `"54 6 "` -> `"546"` is always correct.

Then `join(" ")` will combine the parts together placing spaces between them. Since each part is guaranteed to not have a space, there are no extra spaces, nor is there a need for `.trim()`

### Result

```js
function foo(input) {
  return input
    ?.toUpperCase()
    ?.match(/[0-9\s]+|[a-z]/gi)
    ?.map((part) => part.replace(/\s+/g, "")) // Remove unneeded spaces
    .join(" ") // Revert to one string
}

/*
    54 6 K 1 -> 546 K 1
    54 6k 1 -> 546 K 1
    20 H L -> 20 H L
    1 10 -> 1 10
    546 k1 -> 546 K 1
    1K -> 1 K
*/

console.log("54 6 K 1 ->", foo("54 6 K 1"));
console.log("54 6k 1  ->", foo("54 6k 1"));
console.log("20 H L   ->", foo("20 H L"));
console.log("1 10     ->", foo("1 10"));
console.log("546 k1   ->", foo("546 k1"));
console.log("1K       ->", foo("1K"));

console.log("null           ->", foo(null));
console.log("<empty string> ->", foo(""));
console.log(".,?!:;'        ->", foo(".,?!:;'"));
console.log("             ->", foo(""));
```

Note that `1 10` is converted to `110`. The removal of spaces leaves it as a single number.

Comment: Thanks! 
I really need 1 10 to be separate because that is a common addition.
So i'm ending up with this: 
https://jsbin.com/fipamasoru/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Then what is the rule for that? If it's *only* numbers preserve the spaces? Or perhaps if it's three characters? If you're happy with `54 6k 1`  -> `54 6 K 1` then [you just need this](https://jsbin.com/vilovogeya/1/edit?js,console). If you want both `546` and a `1 10` please describe how to differentiate them. I'd rather not take a guess.

Comment: Tedious example.